# ssl_verify_client (system bus name :1.13917, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)

Tags: nginx, ssl, rhel7

I set the flag ssl_verify_client to on in my configuration file in /etc/nginx/locations and I am getting the following error -

polkitd[1378]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:150916:7856906  (system bus name :1.13917, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus).

Other than the above entry, I don't see anything else that gives more information and the nginx server doesn't restart. How do I rectify the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the file path mentioned in proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate property was improper.